# how to query from multiple tables in sqlite.swift

Tags: sqlite.swift

Is it possible to write a statement in sqlite.swift that will generate the equivalent sql:

SELECT foods.name, food_types.name FROM foods, food_types
WHERE foods.type_id=food_types.id LIMIT 10;

I can't figure out how to query from multiple Table objects at once.
Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Your original query passes two tables to the `FROM` clause, creating an implicit join. SQLite.swift's query builder language currently only supports explicit joins.

Check out the documentation under [Joining Other Tables](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/ccf43925aacf9fcc6130639247b3e7578a1c727a/Documentation/Index.md#joining-other-tables) for more information on joining tables.

In your case:

```swift
let foods = Table("foods")
let food_types = Table("food_types")
let name = Expression<String>("name")
let id = Expression<Int64>("id")
let type_id = Expression<Int64>("type_id")

let query = foods
    .select(foods[name], food_types[name])
    .join(food_types, on: foods[type_id] == food_types[id])
    .limit(10)
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen, I've tried that and it works, I'm running into trouble when I try and join more than two tables, I have multiple tables all with the same foreign key and I'm trying to join on it but I don't get the expected result, I get way more rows than expected. I can do two at a time, and then build my data structure from there, but I was looking for something more elegant. I really appreciate your work and your well designed Sqlite.swift. Cheers.

Comment: Without an example of what isn't working, I unfortunately don't have the ability to help further :( `.join`s can be chained, so you should be able to continue to build up more complex joins.

Comment: Thanks for for the follow up, I think I figured it out. The foreign key is a column for all the tables I'm trying to join, but there are foreign key members that are not common among all the tables so I believe sql then generates a a cross join vs an inner join... That leads to all the extra rows in the query. I confirmed this by using the sql that sqlite.swift generates on the db directly. Thanks again and I'll close out the question

Comment: @stephencelis. I'm not sure anyone in the universe can answer this one other than you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41874682/subtle-cast-warning-when-using-sqlite-swift-binding-to-any  !!  I'm stumped.

Comment: SO well written... thank you! I'd been looking for a good example on how to do this for months and had always just hacked my way around it and now its very clear.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The foreign key is a column for all the tables I'm trying to join, but there are foreign key members that are not common among all the tables so I believe sql then generates a a cross join vs an inner join... That leads to all the extra rows in the query. I confirmed this by using the sql that sqlite.swift generates on the db directly.