# Subtle cast warning when using SQLite.Swift ... Binding? to Any

Tags: swift, sqlite, swift3, option-type, sqlite.swift

Here's one,

```
 import SQLite

    var r:[[Any]] = []

    do {
        if let stmt = try local.db?.prepare(q) {
            r = Array(stmt)
        }
        else {
            print("woe in sql?")
        }
    }
    catch { return [] }
```

the call

```
 r = Array(stmt)
```

gives **Expression implicitly coerced from 'Binding?' to Any.**

[image]

And indeed, I do not know how to Provide a default value to avoid this warning, Force-unwrap the value to avoid this warning, or even Explicitly cast to Any with 'as Any' to silence this warning.  :O

Here's a self-contained example that reproduces the same warning:

```
struct Binding {}

struct Statement : IteratorProtocol, Sequence {
    func next() -> [Binding?]? {
        return nil
    }
}

let stmt = Statement()

let r: [[Any]]

r = Array(stmt) // warning: Expression implicitly coerced from 'Binding?' to Any.
```

---

*Related interesting question:*

Why does the compiler ...

[image]

... appear to not know the line number, with problems like this?  And indeed: why does the warning only arise once you compile?

Most warnings appear right there in the IDE as you're typing, before compilation.

This warning would appear to **(a)** only be known during compiling and **(b)** the compiler doesn't know the line number.

How so? What's the difference?

Comment: Can you make your code self-contained? There are are multiple `prepare()` methods, so it is difficult to tell which one is called here.

Comment: Martin, thanks ..  (a) I don't actually know what you mean by self-contained here (b) unfortunately indeed I can't figure out what the heck call is being used exactly in https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift  :/

Comment: @Hamish: yes, good point: I'm totally in favor of using [[Binding?]].  The thing is, the otherwise awesome SQLite.Swift is a little under-documented regarding the feature of using arbitrary sql calls (which is the only way we use it in the project at hand); for whatever reason the little example code I found kicking around favored [[Any]]. Indeed, I haven't been able to find any good reason to use [[Any]] so we indeed changed to [[Binding?]].  However, the question posted here keeps me up at night.

Comment: Regarding the compiler not knowing what line the warning occurs on – I cannot comment on the cause, but it is fixed in Swift 3.1 with Xcode 8.3 beta :)

Comment: I hope you don't mind @JoeBlow, but I added a self-contained example to your question in order to make it easier for others to reproduce.

Comment: @Hamish - yeah, of course, edit anything anytime - good one

Comment: Doesn't know line number: ah, so basically that was just a bug; no deeper meaning.  Good one!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using `Array`'s [sequence initialiser](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1538750-init), which has the signature:

```
init<S>(_ s: S) where S : Sequence, Element == S.Iterator.Element
```

Because you typed `r` as `[[Any]]`, `Element` is `[Any]`. However, the sequence you're passing in has an [`Iterator.Element` type of `[Binding?]`](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/Sources/SQLite/Core/Statement.swift#L203). Therefore, you're implicitly coercing `Binding?` to `Any`, and as per [SE-0140](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0140-bridge-optional-to-nsnull.md), this will invoke a warning – as you're losing the optionality of the inner elements, which is potentially undesirable.

As the proposal says, one way to silence this warning is to add an explicit `as Any` cast. In your case, this can be achieved by using a nested [`map(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/sequence/1641748-map):

```
r = stmt.map { $0.map { $0 as Any } }
```

[image]

This shouldn't be any more costly than using `Array`'s sequence initialiser due to the fact that a walk over all the inner elements will have to be done in either case, due to the difference in how Swift stores abstract-typed values (see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38387256/2976878) for more info).

However, *really* you should be asking yourself whether `r` should be of type `[[Any]]`. I see no reason why you shouldn't just type it as `[[Binding?]]`. Doing so will both get rid of the warning and give you better type-safety.

Comment: It works!  Bingo, an inner map.  You are the *language mechanic*, dude.

Comment: Happy to help @JoeBlow :)

Comment: sent bounty for great answer

Comment: No worries - young master *language mechanic* !