# Swift Compiler Warning Expression implicitly coerced from UILabel? to Any

Tags: swift, swift3, option-type

I am getting the following Swift Compiler Warning: 
`Expression implicitly coerced from 'UILabel?' to Any`

In addition I found the following messages:

```
<unknown>:0: warning: expression implicitly coerced from 'UILabel?' to Any
<unknown>:0: note: provide a default value to avoid this warning
<unknown>:0: note: force-unwrap the value to avoid this warning
<unknown>:0: note: explicitly cast to Any with 'as Any' to silence this warning
```

But I am not exactly sure why.
This is the code where I use the `UILabel`

```
class MyCell: UITableViewCell {
    var primaryLabel: UILabel!
    var secondaryLabel: UILabel!

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:)")
    }

    init(_ row: myStruct) {
        super.init(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "myId")
        primaryLabel = {
            let l = UILabel(frame: .zero)
            ...
            l.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            return l
        }()
        self.addSubview(primaryLabel)

        if row.subtitle != nil {
            secondaryLabel = {
                let l = UILabel(frame: .zero)
                ...
                l.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                return l
            }()
            self.addSubview(secondaryLabel)
        }

        ... 
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Or how can I safely mute the compiler?

Thanks

Comment: Where is the `print` statement which causes the warning? in Swift 3 the warning occurs when trying to print an optional value.

Comment: On what line are you getting the warning?

Comment: Can you please specify where the error occurs?

Comment: @Hamish It doesn't give a line number - I searched my source code for `UILabels` and this is pretty much one of the only spots I found them. Iget the warning a total of 5 times.

Comment: @Xcoder123 when building. here an image: http://imgur.com/a/x9CFX

Comment: Try cleaning your build folder and rebuilding @Joseph – the compiler should indicate the line (if it even still warns after rebuilding). Although now that I come to think of it, there is a problem in Xcode 8.2.1 where the compiler sometimes cannot locate the line of the warning (which is fixed in Xcode 8.3 beta). Might be worth downloading the beta to locate the warning.

Comment: @vadian I am not printing anything with `UILabels`

Comment: It's because you do not unwrap the optionals. Try using **guard**, **if-let** statements or (I strongly do not recommend this) force unwrap them. But it should specify the exact lines of the error... strange

Comment: @Hamish I tried Project > Clean and I did Watchdog > Clean Now.

Comment: Are you sure that this class is causing the errors?

Comment: @Xcoder123 but they are not optional `var primaryLabel: UILabel!`

Comment: I suspect the error occurs somewhere else. Is anything displayed in the Issue Navigator (⌘4)?

Comment: It is totally not caused by this class, search somewhere else in your project

Comment: @vadian nope http://imgur.com/a/xOi9N

Comment: Check all your print statements everywhere. Once again this warning is displayed typically when printing optionals. And usually when you click on the warning in Issue Navigator it shows you the line in code.

Comment: If you click on the warnings, does it "jump" to any section of your code, if so where?

Comment: @Joseph Do you have any `[UILabel?]`'s in your project? Could be related to http://stackoverflow.com/q/41874682/2976878. Like I said in my previous (edited) comment, the simplest way to locate the warning would be to download Xcode 8.3 beta, which fixed the issue of not being able to find the line for this given warning.

Comment: @Xcoder123 nope - that is what I can't explain either. I don't have any other `UILabels` in my code.

Comment: @vadian only have 1 print statement in my code and it prints the object created a few lines above it. commenting it out had no effect.

Comment: try closing and reopening Xcode and do thatt again

Comment: @Hamish nope like I wrote these are the only `UILabel`s in use. To make sure I commented the other two instances of `UILabel` out and still got the error. Restarted Xcode as well.

Comment: After restarting I do now get a slightly changed error message. It has to be this file: http://imgur.com/a/fs4EP and those are the only `UILabels`
 in the file